# Nvidia / Wayland / Ubuntu 18.04 : Unable to find display on any available system

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, graphics, wayland

System :

- Ubuntu 18.04,
- Linux 4.15.0-39-generic
- nvidia 390.77 driver, installed from the sources/drivers manager
- Gnome 3.28.2, Wayland session, gdm3
- Nvidia Prime laptop, HDMI output wired on the discrete GPU

Issues :

when launching nvidia-settings, I get this error :

```
$ nvidia-settings 

ERROR: Unable to find display on any available system
```

Synaptic doesn't launch (error message translated from French):

```
$ sudo synaptic
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Unable to connect : Connection refused

(synaptic:5188): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:19:42.755: cannot open display: :0
```

If I try `gksu` instead of `sudo` (which is bad, I know), the GTK password window doesn't capture the text input, so the password gets written in clear in the terminal used to launch it.

`glxgears` works, but at a ridiculous 60 FPS. The HDMI external monitor doesn't work.

Why I want/need Wayland :

I mostly use the GPU for OpenCL computations (and external display wiring). Using Xorg (which works), the vRAM gets up to 1066 MiB sucked by Gnome Shell + Xorg. Using Wayland, it's only 75 MiB. Gnome + Xorg seem to have serious memory leaks, their RAM footprint increases as the OS is running.

Already tested :

The usual:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove --purge nvidia*
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo reboot
```

Then reinstall Nvidia + reboot.

Comment: Wayland does not work with nvidia.  In the past, when the nvidia drivers were installed,  Wayland was not even offered, but recently, it is offered, but will automatically switch to the integrated (Intel?) drivers -- hence the failure of the nvidia-settings.  You can still access the GPU, the non-graphics CUDA samples will still work.